# ggplot in shiny: geom_line(aes(colour = variable)), fails when variable is only a single factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

In shiny I have built an app that plots various price data into a chart. I am plotting such that:

- x-axis = date
- y-axis = price
- colour = variable (in this case trading model and model name is
  listen in a column named variable after I used `melt()`)

I have a selectInput box in the ui which filters out models that the user doesn't want to use by filtering `ccy2.price.melt`.

Everything works perfectly, until I leave only 1 model to show. Then the following error is kicked up:

> Error: incorrect number of dimensions

I'm assuming it is to do with:

> aes(colour = variable)

Is ther a way around this so that I can use this code to plot the required chart when only plotting one model?

```
model.fixed.colours <- reactive ({ cbind(c("unhedged", "custom", "hedged", "quant"), c(input$unhedged.colour, input$custom.colour, input$hedged.colour, input$quant.colour)) })


ccy2.models.price <- reactive({


    models <- c()

    if("Unhedged" %in% input$models.for.price.chart) {
            models <- append(models, "unhedged")
    }
    if("Custom" %in% input$models.for.price.chart) {
            models <- append(models, "custom")
    }
    if("Hedged" %in% input$models.for.price.chart) {
            models <- append(models, "hedged")
    }
    if("QUANT" %in% input$models.for.price.chart)   {
            models <- append(models, "quant")
    }

    models
```

})

```
output$ccy2.price <- renderPlot ({

    values <- ccy2.price.melt()[ccy2.price.melt()$variable %in% ccy2.models.price(),]
    colour <- model.fixed.colours()[model.fixed.colours()[,1] %in% ccy2.models.price(),]

    ggplot(values, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
            geom_line(aes(colour = variable), size = 1) +
            theme_bw() +
            scale_color_manual(values = colour[,2]) +
            labs(colour = "") +
            xlab("Date") + 
            ggtitle(paste("Average ", input$ccy2, "/", input$base.ccy, " FX Rate ", sep = "" )) +
            theme(plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold", margin = margin(10, 0, 10, 0))) +
            theme(panel.border = element_blank()) +
            theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 0.5), axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.5)) +
            theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NULL, color = "white")) +
            guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4))) +

            scale_y_continuous("FX Rate", limits = c(min.ccy2.price(),max.ccy2.price()))
```

})

Comment: Use `browser()` inside your `renderPlot({...})` to take a closer look at what your values and colour actually look like at that point. (You will have to jump through the `browser()` a few times until you have your inputs set to reproduce the error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the line `scale_colour_manual(values = colour[,2])`

When you only have one variable this is a vector instead of a matrix, thus when you ask for `[,2]`, you are asking for the something in the second dimension of a 1 dim object. Try making this a `data.frame` instead of a matrix.

```
model.fixed.colours <- reactive ({
 data.frame(Name = c("unhedged", "custom", "hedged", "quant"),
  Colour = c(input$unhedged.colour, input$custom.colour, input$hedged.colour, input$quant.colour)) 
})
```

then replacing that line with

```
scale_color_manual(values = colour$Colour) +
```

and

```
colour <- subset(model.fixed.colours(),Name  %in% ccy2.models.price())
```

Comment: This calls up an error if I run as is and i think its becasue: "scale_color_manual(values = colour$colour) +". If I change it to colour$Colour The chart shows, however it is ignoring my colour choices. I've had a play and can't for the life of me work it out

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the code you have provided. I suggest taking a look using the `browser()` function. It will pause execution of shiny and give you a command line in that environment. Then you can take a close look at what values the variables actually have. (You are right, I had a capitalization typo, should be `Colour`)

Comment: Ok so I finally worked it out. The inputs in the model.fixed.colours variable were Hexadecimals. In converting to a dataframe I think these lost their character format some how? Any way by making this modification it all works fine: scale_color_manual(values = as.character(colour$Colour)) +